# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[this is the error i m getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MqXD.png)This question is asked many time. But the following code runs well in online compiler but not in my local system even the system is connected to internet then also it shows angular is not defined

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"/><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"/><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: where is the reference for angular and ngRoute?

Comment: Please follow this 


  http://plnkr.co/edit/Tj5qVMkKwnWXO068RZSs?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Change your controller like this,

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
  <br>
  <br>Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: then also it is working in online compiler only. but not in my project

Comment: @R.Raj:It means your reference for angular and ngRoute is not correct

Comment: @R.Raj :Where you place your these references?

Comment: where to place this references??

Comment: In your project directory